# clusterExport to single thread in R parallel

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, bigdata

I would like to split a large `data.frame` into chunks and pass each individually to the different members of the cluster.

Something like:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
for (i in 1:detectCores()) {
  clusterExport(cl, mydata[indices[[i]]], <extra option to specify a thread/process>)
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You probably need to read some help pages for `parallel` package.

Comment: @Pascal I've had a quick look at the vignette that comes up first on Google. It doesn't seem to address this issue. Could you point me to the info that does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that uses `clusterCall` inside a `for` loop to send a different chunk of the data frame to each of the workers:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10)
ix <- splitIndices(nrow(df), length(cl))
for (i in seq_along(cl)) {
  clusterCall(cl[i], function(d) {
    assign('mydata', d, pos=.GlobalEnv)
    NULL  # don't return any data to the master
  }, df[ix[[i]],,drop=FALSE])
}
```

Note that the call to `clusterCall` is subsetting `cl` in order to execute the function on a single worker each time through the `for` loop.

You can verify that the workers were properly initialized in this example using:

```
r <- do.call('rbind', clusterEvalQ(cl, mydata))
identical(df, r)
```

There are easier ways to do this, but this example minimizes the memory used by the master and the amount of data sent to each of the workers. This is important when the data frame is very large.

Comment: Thanks so much @SteveWeston. This seems to work. The only problem with this is I had to reorder the ``r`` data.frame to verify the workers were properly initialized. I'll accept the answer once you the order of pulling the data back is made explicit. Thanks again!

Comment: @kennyB `clusterEvalQ` should always return the results in "worker order". So when you run this code, `identical(df, r)` does not return `TRUE`?

Comment: This particular code does return true, and I worked out the the problem I was having. I had split the ``data.frame`` by an id variable that wasn't the id variable the ``data.frame`` was sorted on. So collecting it back up made the order change.

Comment: Hi @SteveWeston. I am also looking for a way to partition large datasets for memory efficient parallel computing in R. I had success using your code to partition the dataset and process the partitions independently on each core, but was unable to get your loop to work in parallel instead of consecutively. Do you know of a way in Windows OS that I could run your clusterCall() in parallel, and if not do you know if there is an alternative solution to partitioning and exporting the data that is compatible with foreach?