# Send chunks of large dataset to specific cores for R parallel foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, chunking

I am attempting to scale a script that involves applying a feature extraction function on a image file generated using data from each row of an R matrix. For faster computation I split the matrix into equally sized chunks and run each chunk in R `parallel` using the `foreach` structure. To do this, I have to send the entire matrix to each core using `clusterExport` and subset it to desired chunk within the `foreach` loop.

I am hoping to find a way to export only the matrix chunks to each core, instead of passing the full matrix to each core and then subsetting. I was only able to find one thread close to what I was looking for, [this answer by Steve Weston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068289/clusterexport-to-single-thread-in-r-parallel/31075231#comment101123857_31075231) who sent individual chunks to each core using `clusterCall` (code pasted below)

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10)
ix <- splitIndices(nrow(df), length(cl))
for (i in seq_along(cl)) {
  clusterCall(cl[i], function(d) {
    assign('mydata', d, pos=.GlobalEnv)
    NULL  # don't return any data to the master
  }, df[ix[[i]],,drop=FALSE])
}
```

This answer worked as advertised, however, the cores in this example run in sequence instead of parallel. My attempt to parallelize this using `foreach` instead of `for` was hamstrung by having to use `clusterExport` to transfer the dataset variable, which is the issue I'm trying to avoid

```
clusterExport(cl,c("df","ix"))
foreach() %dopar% {etc}
```

Is there a way to pass chunks of a variable to each core, and operate on them in parallel? A foreach solution would be nice, or a parallelized adaptation to Steve Weston's structure. Note that I am developing for Windows, so forking is not an option for me.

Comment: If you're working with matrices (not data frames), you might want to look at on-disk matrices (simplifies parallelism). Look at packages {bigmemory} and {bigstatsr}.

Comment: Thank you @F.Privé, that sent me on the right track. I am working with matrices, but data frames would probably be possible by just saving chunks of your data on disk as different .csv files, and then loading these into each core. I think bigmemory files are compressed and so probably a lot more efficient, but if disk space isn't a huge consideration it could be a solution.

Comment: I don't think {bigmemory} files are compressed. It is just binary files storing each element of the matrix in order.